# async execution using twisted matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, twisted

I'm trying to developing a simple twisted matrix example with the aim to perform async execution of a function but the print seams to tell me the execution is in sync or in sequential order, where is my misunderstanding?

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
import time, random

def _print_(x):
    print "BAR", x

@inlineCallbacks
def sqrt(x):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    r = yield x*2
    print "FOO", r
    returnValue(r)

if __name__=='__main__':

    for dd in map(sqrt, range(10)):
        dd.addCallback(_print_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted does not turn blocking code into non-blocking code nor synchronous code into asynchronous code.  It gives you tools for writing asynchronous code.

`inlineCallbacks` is essentially the same thing as `Deferred` but with a different API.  It doesn't change the single-threaded, cooperative multi-tasking nature of Twisted.

The program you've posted sequentially calls sqrt on the integers in range(10).  Each call to `sqrt` sleeps for a random amount of time and then computes a result.  The computation all happens in a single thread and so only one thing can happen at a time.  When the sleep is happening, nothing else is.

What you can do is use one of Twisted's helpers to replace the blocking `time.sleep()` call:

```
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.internet import reactor

@inlineCallbacks
def sqrt(x):
    yield deferLater(reactor, random.random(), lambda: None)
    r = yield x*2
    print "FOO", r
    returnValue(r)
```

Now `sqrt` does not block in a `time.sleep()` call.  Instead, it gives up control to the reactor.  `deferLater(...)` returns a `Deferred` that will be fired for you after the given delay with the result of the given function (in this case the function is irrelevant since you only want to sleep, but `deferLater` requires *some* function).

Combined with `inlineCallbacks`, this gives you a "sleep" without *blocking* the reactor thread.  The reactor is free to find other events to process while time is passing until it is time for the `deferLater(...)` `Deferred` to fire.  When that happens, execution can resume inside `sqrt` and the computation can proceed.  Of course, note that the computation itself is still blocking.  However, since it's a simple integer multiplication, it probably doesn't block for long enough to matter.

The `deferLater` solution is specific to `time.sleep`.  If you have other forms of blocking, you may need to learn about other APIs which address them.

You may also want to read [How do I add two integers together with Twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313761/how-do-i-add-two-integers-together-with-twisted)

Comment: Ok got it thank a lot! I read from the post you link taht "twisted is for network code. Everything else is just normal python.". Does it mean that in case I have more time consuming function instead of my stupid *sqrt* function I cannot think to obtain better perfornamces running them in parallel?

Comment: If you want to accelerate CPU-bound operations, you may want to investigate options for running multiple Python processes (assuming you have multiple CPUs available to take advantage of, which you probably do these days).  CPython doesn't make for a favorable platform for using multithreading to attack CPU-bound problems (PyPy might).